# How to create language select drop down list using unordered list only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide

Basically I want to create a language drop down list with flags, and with Germany as default.

First,  created a div and inside

- an `img` which represent the german flag and a `p` tag which contains the country name
- and then `ul` list whit other counties which I hide with css, so the german country is the only one shown by default

However, that way, I couldn't show other countries once one of them was clicked on; using jquery.

So what I want to do is to put all languages inside `ul` with list items, but this broke my original style

Can any one help me with the style so I can know how I can show the german language `li` by default, and when someone clicks on another language, the default changes with jquery  ?

Here is the code i have so far :

```css
body {

    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #ddd;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #333;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.wrapper-country-dropdown {

    position: relative; 
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.wrapper-country-dropdown:after {

    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -3px;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #444 transparent;
}

.wrapper-country-dropdown .country-dropdown-list {

    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    list-style: none;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.wrapper-country-dropdown .country-dropdown-list li a {

    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #838383;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper-country-dropdown .country-dropdown-list a > img{margin-left: 5px;

}

.flag-icon {
    padding-right: 5px;
    float: left;
}

p { 
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline;
}

/* Hover  */

.wrapper-country-dropdown .country-dropdown-list li:hover a {
    color: grey;
}

/* Active  */

.wrapper-country-dropdown.active:after {
    border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.wrapper-country-dropdown.active .country-dropdown-list {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

     <div id="dd" class="wrapper-country-dropdown">

      <img src="images/flage/england.png" class="flag-icon">

      <p>England</p>

      <ul class="country-dropdown-list">

      <li>
        <a href="#">
         <img src="images/flage/england.png" class="flag-icon">
         <p class="country-name">Germany</p>
        </a>
       </li>

       <li>
        <a href="#">
         <img src="images/flage/germany.png" class="flag-icon">
         <p class="country-name">England</p>
        </a>
       </li>

       <li>
        <a href="#">
         <img src="images/flage/france.png" class="flag-icon">
         <p class="country-name">France</p>
        </a>
       </li>
      </ul>
      
     </div><!-- end wrapper country dropdown -->

 </div><!-- enc container-->
```

Comment: You didn't add any code, bud.

Comment: Why not use `select` and `option`? It is not entirely clear to me what you mean by dropdown.

Comment: you want the selected value in select box right.

Comment: @ahmed mansi I updated your answer, with your css code (through the "edit" button that is below it). I think some javascript code is still missing. I am not saying you should further edit your question because you can probably find your answers in one of the many tutorials online. However, this should give you an idea of how to formulate your question a little better (there is a "preview" box when you write a question, use it !). Also, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 0):

you can create List in following way.

```
<select name="teste " id="teste ">
     <option >  <li>Coffee</li> </option>
     <option selected="selected">   <li>Tea</li> </option> 
     <option>  <li>Milk</li> </option> 
</select>
```

where **selected="selected"** that field is by default selected.

you can get that value in jquery through.

```
$( "#teste  option:selected" ).text();
```

you can refer to following url for more.

[Jquery selector](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/)